# How to get the earliest date of a List in Java?

Tags: java, date, compare

I have an ArrayList which stores 0...4 Dates.

The amount of Dates in the list depends on a Business logic.

How can I get the earliest date of this list? Of course I can build iterative loops to finally retrieve the earliest date. But is there a 'cleaner'/ quicker way of doing this, especially when considering that this list can grow on a later perspective?

Comment: @AndyTurner , you should post this comment as an answer.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) implements `Comparable<Date>`, so you can simply use:

```
Date minDate = Collections.min(listOfDates);
```

This relies on there being at least one element in the list. If the list might be empty (amongst many other approaches):

```
Optional<Date> minDate = listOfDates.stream().min(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

Answer (score 0):

## `SortedSet`

Depending on your application you can think about using a [`SortedSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html) (like `TreeSet`). This allows you to change the collection and always receive the lowest element easily.

Adding elements to the collection is more expensive, though.

Answer (score -1):

If you dont mind to change the insertion order then sort the list and get the elemeent at index 0

Comment: Sorting the list is an `O(n log n)` operation. You can find the minimum element in `O(n)` simply by iterating the list.